# Is there a way i can run typescript/javascript in deepnote easily with a docker image?

Tags: typescript, docker, deepnote

I am trying to run typescript in deepnote, since it supports docker image i stupidly started slapping node+python docker images like [nikolaik/python-nodejs:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs)
hoping it would work but to no avail.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible, you can find some inspiration in [my post in Deepnote Community](https://community.deepnote.com/c/showcase/typescript-in-deepnote) or clone [this particular notebook](https://deepnote.com/workspace/jz-d0f7bed4-4e26-4bb6-812a-fd327eb3edc1/project/TypeScript-environment-ecd62d8f-d48d-4e99-a11d-b381d99ed9b7/notebook/notebook-12852eaa582d4c7394a995c1f0153264).

It is based on the [tslab kernel](https://github.com/yunabe/tslab) for Jupyter. Here is how my Dockerfile looks like exactly:

```
FROM deepnote/python:3.10

ENV NODE_VERSION=18.16.0
ENV NVM_DIR=/opt/nvm
RUN mkdir $NVM_DIR

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="${NVM_DIR}/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version

# Installing tslab is problematic as root
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash tslab-installer
RUN chmod -R 777 /opt/nvm
RUN sudo -u tslab-installer sh -c ' \
    export NVM_DIR=/opt/nvm; \
    . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}; \
    . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}; \
    . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}; \
    PATH="/opt/nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"; \
    /opt/nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm i -g tslab'

RUN pip install jupyter
RUN tslab install

ENV NODE_PATH "${NVM_DIR}/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/lib/node_modules"
ENV DEFAULT_KERNEL_NAME "tslab"
```

Here is a bit more info about [Custom Environments](https://deepnote.com/docs/custom-environments) and [Custom kernels](https://deepnote.com/docs/running-your-own-kernel) in Deepnote docs.